# type friendly delegation in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

Consider the following code sample

```py
def sum(a: int, b: int):
  return a + b

def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
  # delegate to sum
  return sum(*args, **kwargs)
```

The code works well except that type hint is lost.
It's very common in Python to use `*args, **kwargs` to implement delegation pattern. It would be great to have a way to keep the type hint while using them, but I don't know if it is possible and how.

Comment: No. I am looking for a way that allow IDE or type checking tool that can derive the typing automatically.

Comment: There are ways to make this work at run time. Functions can have a `__signature__` attribute copied from a wrapped function, for example, and the `inspect` module will respect it even if the wrapper function is defined with `*args, **kwargs`. `functools.wraps()` copies the signature object appropriately. I don't know how widely this is supported in IDEs since it only happens at runtime; PyCharm didn't really "get it" when I used `@functools.wraps(sum)` on your `wrap` function.

Comment: See [PEP 362](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0362/) for more information on function signature objects.

Comment: Thanks @kindall It is good to know to have a solution working at the run time, it will make debugging much easier. I know that Python is so dynamic that maybe no solution to solve this issue in the typing system. I find that [PEP 612](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0612/) maybe a potential one but I didn't test it yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See https://github.com/python/typing/issues/270 for a long discussion of this problem. You can achieve this by decorating `wrap` with an appropriately typed identity function:

```py
F = TypeVar("F", bound=Callable)
def copy_signature(_: F) -> Callable[..., F]:
    return lambda f: f

def s(x: int, y: int) -> int:
    return x + y

@copy_signature(s)
def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
    s(*args, **kwargs)

reveal_type(wrap)  # Revealed type is "def (x: int, y: int) -> int"
```

As far as I know, the decorator is necessary - it is still not possible to do this using type hints alone, even with PEP612. Since it was already good practice to use the `functools.wraps` decorator in this situation (which copies the *runtime* type information), this is not such a loss - you could instead define

```py
def wraps(f: F) -> Callable[..., F]:
    return functools.wraps(f) # type: ignore
```

and then both the runtime and static type information should be correct so long as you use this decorator. (Sadly the typeshed stubs for `functools.wraps` included with mypy aren't quite restrictive enough to get this working out of the box.)

PEP612 adds the ability to add/remove arguments in your wrapper (by combining `ParamSpec` with `Concatenate`), but it doesn't remove the need for some kind of higher-order function (like a decorator) to let the type system infer the signature of `wrap` from that of `s`.

Comment: I think that's the right way to do so and the IDE can also derive typing correclty.